# How to instanciate a List of POGOs within a POGO

Tags: groovy

I am trying to apply a Groovy object model on a complex JSON structure.

I implemented all the POGOs I needed to modelize this JSON but I just realized that the default Map constructor was not automatically instanciating the Objects withing Lists (and this is the expected behavior I guess).

```
class Foo {
    String fooKey


    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
            "fooKey='" + fooKey + '\'' +
            '}'
    }
}

class Toto {
    Foo foo
    List<Foo> foos

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "Toto{" +
            "foos=" + foos +
            ", foo=" + foo +
            '}'
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Toto toto = new Toto(["foo": ["fooKey": "fooVal"], "foos": [["fooKey": "fooVal"]]])

    println toto
    println toto.foo instanceof Foo
    println toto.foos instanceof List<Foo>
    println toto.foos.get(0) instanceof Foo

    println ""
    println "--------------"
    println ""

    Foo foo = new Foo()
    println foo instanceof Foo
    println foo
}
```

Which outputs the following :

```
Toto{foos=[[fooKey:fooVal]], foo=Foo{fooKey='fooVal'}}
true
true
false <----- This is the problem

--------------

true
Foo{fooKey='null'}
```

Is there a way to instanciate my `List<Foo>` without overriding the default constructor by myself ?

Comment: [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) seems to be able to parse JSON into complex objects. `@Grab( 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5' )
import com.google.gson.Gson
    Toto toto = new Gson().fromJson('{"foo": {"fooKey": "fooVal"}, "foos": [{"fooKey": "fooVal"}]}', Toto)`

Comment: @hsan Thanks for the reply but I was hoping for a "native" way to handle that with Groovy, which does not exist I'm afraid :/

Comment: Groovy wont turn the childs into proper classes.  It will just assign the list of maps. You would have to shape the data beforehand (e.g. `json.foos = json.foos.collect{ new Foo(it) }`. This becomes tedious very quickly and you are better off using GSON, Jackson, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hsan and cfrick for mentionning that there is no "native" way to handle this.

The best solution is to use a JSON parsing library. I went for Jackson because it is already used somewhere else in my Groovy execution context, which allows me to reuse the dependency.